# Sizing a box appropriately for two columns of information but minimum size of both columns

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a reorderable list view where the list items all have a content area and a control area.

The control area to the right has the up / drag / down icons to tell the user they can move it up / down using the buttons or use drag behavior (long press).

When the user tries to drag, looks like the reorderable list view is creating a layer on top and moving the widget into it and so for the items in the background to be visible I have to set the height parameters properly ( it is vertical reorder able list).
so am using a constrained box to set min and max heights but I can't make. it to work like I want to.
[image: ListView Item look]
I would like the overall card to be as min height as possible. I need the height to be the same when the user is actually trying to reorder the item by dragging ( this is important as otherwise the screen is being covered by the card and makes it impossible for the user to reorder.)

I want the columns with the icons below to be using the max height as possible but not greater than the height of the left data column.

My widgets tree look like this.

```
ConstrainedBox(
  minHeight: 100,
  maxHeight: 300,
 Card(
  Row(
   Expanded(
    Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     Text(),
     Control(),
     Text(),
    )//Column
   )//Expanded
   Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    IconButton(uparrow)
    Icon(Drag)
    IconButton(downarrow)
   )//Column
  )//Row
 )//Card
)//ConstrainedBox
```

Answer (score 0):

After more googling I found a heavy solution - intrinsic height and also a problem with that solution (maybe a bug).
My widget tree now looks like this.

```
ConstrainedBox(
  minHeight: 100,
  maxHeight: 300,
 Card(
  IntrinsicHeight(
   Row(
    Expanded(
     Column(
       //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      Text(),
      Container(
        height:60,
       TextField(),
      )//container
      Text(),
     )//Column
    )//Expanded
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     IconButton(uparrow)
     Icon(Drag)
     IconButton(downarrow)
    )//Column
   )//Row
  )//IntrinsicHeight
 )//Card
)//ConstrainedBox
```

While this works, it is not recommended much due to the heavy nature of this widget. I am using it in a list and don't see much effect to performance but my list is in the range of 10 items. not very large.

The issue I found is that when I had a text field in data column and the text field had any semantics the calculation was wrong and the control was giving me the dreaded out of box warning / yellow paint. it was exactly 5 pixels problem.
If I did not use the the semantics it was fine.
The semantics I was using was the maxLength attribute of the text field which puts a number below the text field. Using Material widgets.
That is why I had to wrap the text field in height container to avoid the problem and give a simple size to the intrinsic height calculator.
[image: fixed view]